# Need Regular Expression to validate string

Tags: java, regex

Could you please help in creating a regular expression which can validate the following string of below format in Java?

The string contains key and value separated by a colon(:). These key and value pairs are further separated by either an & or | symbol.

```
"key:value"|"key:value"&"key:value"|"key:value"
```

Here key is string which can have only alphabets.
Here value is alphanumeric.

Comment: You should look in a java tutorial about the parsing of regular expressions... But here it doesn't look like you did your own search.

Comment: Try `"(?i)\"[a-z]+:[a-z0-9]+\"([|&]\"[a-z]+:[a-z0-9]+\")*"`.

Comment: Thankyou for your inputs. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
("\w+:\w+"[\|\&]?)+
```

This will match in order:

```
"
1 or more word characters [a-zA-Z0-9]
:
1 or more word characters [a-zA-Z0-9]
"
0 or 1  | or & character
```

and this, 1 or more times

And I agree with J. Chomel, this is not higher level regex so with a little bit of research, you should have been able to figure it out yourself.

Have a look at these websites for more info on regex:

http://regexone.com/

http://regex101.com/